# Error after Rails upgrade from 5.2 to 6.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activesupport

I'm getting an error when trying to execute tasks like `active_storage:update` or `zeitwerk:check` since upgrading from rails 5.2.4.4 to rails 6.1

Here is the error and stack trace I'm getting:

```
NoMethodError: private method 'try' called for #<ActiveSupport::Notifications::Fanout::Subscribers::Evented:0x0000562c0ed02e98>
Did you mean?  try!
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.4/lib/active_support/notifications/fanout.rb:46:in 'block in unsubscribe'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/mutex_m.rb:78:in 'synchronize'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/mutex_m.rb:78:in 'mu_synchronize'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.4/lib/active_support/notifications/fanout.rb:39:in 'unsubscribe'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:250:in 'unsubscribe'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/lograge-0.11.2/lib/lograge.rb:121:in 'block (2 levels) in unsubscribe'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/lograge-0.11.2/lib/lograge.rb:119:in 'each'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/lograge-0.11.2/lib/lograge.rb:119:in 'block in unsubscribe'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/lograge-0.11.2/lib/lograge.rb:118:in 'each'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/lograge-0.11.2/lib/lograge.rb:118:in 'unsubscribe'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/lograge-0.11.2/lib/lograge.rb:109:in 'block in remove_existing_log_subscriptions'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/lograge-0.11.2/lib/lograge.rb:106:in 'each'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/lograge-0.11.2/lib/lograge.rb:106:in 'remove_existing_log_subscriptions'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/lograge-0.11.2/lib/lograge.rb:202:in 'keep_original_rails_log'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/lograge-0.11.2/lib/lograge.rb:130:in 'setup'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/lograge-0.11.2/lib/lograge/railtie.rb:11:in 'block in <class:Railtie>'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:68:in 'block in execute_hook'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:61:in 'with_execution_control'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:66:in 'execute_hook'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:52:in 'block in run_load_hooks'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:51:in 'each'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:51:in 'run_load_hooks'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-6.1.4.4/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:140:in 'block in <module:Finisher>'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-6.1.4.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in 'instance_exec'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-6.1.4.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in 'run'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-6.1.4.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in 'block in run_initializers'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:228:in 'block in tsort_each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:350:in 'block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:431:in 'each_strongly_connected_component_from'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:349:in 'block in each_strongly_connected_component'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:347:in 'each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:347:in 'call'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:347:in 'each_strongly_connected_component'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:226:in 'tsort_each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:205:in 'tsort_each'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-6.1.4.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in 'run_initializers'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-6.1.4.4/lib/rails/application.rb:391:in 'initialize!'
/project-name/config/environment.rb:5:in '<main>'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/bootsnap-1.9.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in 'require'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/bootsnap-1.9.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in 'block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/bootsnap-1.9.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:88:in 'register'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/bootsnap-1.9.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in 'require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/bootsnap-1.9.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in 'require'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/zeitwerk-2.5.3/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:35:in 'require'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in 'block in require'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:299:in 'load_dependency'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in 'require'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-6.1.4.4/lib/rails/application.rb:367:in 'require_environment!'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-6.1.4.4/lib/rails/application.rb:533:in 'block in run_tasks_blocks'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in 'block in execute'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in 'each'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in 'execute'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:219:in 'block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in 'synchronize'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in 'invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:243:in 'block in invoke_prerequisites'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in 'each'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in 'invoke_prerequisites'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:218:in 'block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in 'synchronize'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in 'invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:188:in 'invoke'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in 'invoke_task'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in 'block (2 levels) in top_level'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in 'each'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in 'block in top_level'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:125:in 'run_with_threads'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in 'top_level'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-6.1.4.4/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:24:in 'block (2 levels) in perform'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in 'standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-6.1.4.4/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:24:in 'block in perform'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:59:in 'with_application'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-6.1.4.4/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:18:in 'perform'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-6.1.4.4/lib/rails/command.rb:50:in 'invoke'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-6.1.4.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in '<main>'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/bootsnap-1.9.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in 'require'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/bootsnap-1.9.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in 'block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/bootsnap-1.9.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:105:in 'register'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/bootsnap-1.9.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in 'require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/bootsnap-1.9.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in 'require'
/project-name/bin/rails:5:in '<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in 'load'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in 'call'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in 'call'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in 'run'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/spring-2.1.1/bin/spring:49:in '<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in 'load'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in '<top (required)>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:72:in 'require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:72:in 'require'
/project-name/bin/spring:10:in 'block in <top (required)>'
/project-name/bin/spring:7:in 'tap'
/project-name/bin/spring:7:in '<top (required)>'
bin/rails:2:in 'load'
bin/rails:2:in '<main>'
Tasks: TOP => active_storage:update => environment
```

Does anyone has any clue about it?

Comment: Without more context it's hard to help you, but you can call private methods with `.send()` like `instance.send(:try, args)`.

Comment: `instance.send(:try, args)` works fine. The issue is when I try execute rails tasks